# Case Statement Null Issues

Tags: sql-server-2012

I always get null value issues whenever I try to use a case statement on a data from the same column.
Data in database:

```
Month   Sum
Jan     1000
Feb     2000
Mar     3000
```

Desired Result:

```
Jan    Feb     Mar
1000   2000    3000
```

When I tried using case statement I was running into null issue and was getting results like below:

```
Jan      Feb      Mar
1000     Null     Null
Null     2000     Null
Null     Null     3000
```

Here is the code that creates null value issue.

```
select AccountID,
sum(Case when DATEPART(month,EndDateTime) = 10 then Budget End) period1,
sum(case when DATEPART(month,EndDateTime) = 11 then Budget end) period2,
sum(case  when DATEPART(month,EndDateTime) = 12 then Budget End) period3,
Description,
from Budget
where DATEPART(month,EndDateTime) in ('10','11','12')
group by AccountID,Description,EndDateTime
order by AccountID,Description,EndDateTime;
```

---

Using Pivot function I was able to generate the desired result.

```
SELECT
    AccountID,
    [1] AS Jan,
    [2] AS Feb,
    [3] AS Mar,
    [4] AS Apr,
    [5] AS May,
    [6] AS Jun,
    [7] AS Jul,
    [8] AS Aug,
    [9] AS Sep,
    [10] AS Oct,
    [11] AS Nov,
    [12] AS Dec
FROM
(Select 
AccountID,
Budget,
 MONTH(EndDateTime) as TMonth
  from
    dbo.Budget) source
PIVOT
(
    SUM(Budget)
    FOR TMonth
    IN ( [1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9], [10], [11], [12] )
) AS pvtMonth
```

The current issue I am now having is that I need to add one more sum function Sum(BudgetNet). Any suggestions?
Thanks.

Comment: Are you wrapping your `CASE` expressions expressions with an aggregate, like `MAX()`?

Comment: Remove `EndDateTime` from the `GROUP BY` list (and also from the `ORDER BY`). You're not grouping by something you're aggregating!

Comment: Will that remove all the null values and result me only one row instead of 3? If I don't order by EndDateTime, it doesn't sort the result by month.

Comment: Please can you add your table dbo.budget structure/columns to the question so it will be easy for others to understand your requirement better?

Answer (score 0):

For the type of result that you are wanting, it looks like you should be using [PIVOT](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx) instead of CASE.

Comment: Exactly. Pivot is what I was thinking of using. So do you think the null values problems occur because of the case statement? Pivot can eliminate that issue, right?

Comment: I think so. When you use a case statement, it's still going to return the total number of rows, in this case three, but since you're parsing out only the data that you want with CASE, it's just filling in the unused cells with NULL.

PIVOT seems to be pretty much designed to handle this exact situation.

Comment: Yes, I am going to need to get used to pivot. However, using months in pivot was getting little complicated. Then I have two aggr function to use (budget and cummulative budget) so it gets even more complicated.

Comment: Do you think you can help me create the pivot code based on the faulty query I posted? Thanks.